# Diffuse russian text

Tags: dvipdf

I use some russian text in my file and when I compile it to pdf text becomes diffuse and transparent. How can I fix it? (To compile source file I use `latex + dvipdfm`, MikTex version 2.9)

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}

\usepackage[landscape, left=0.7cm, right=0cm, top=1.5cm, bottom=0.4cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{Left}
\fancyhead[R]{Right}
\fancyheadoffset{-0.5cm}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{russian}

Hello world!

Привет мир!

\end{document}
```

Comment: Try first installing the `CM-Super` package

Comment: Probably the cyrillic fonts are type 3 (bitmapped) instead of type 2 (vectorial). You can check this looking at the fonts used in the final pdf (Adobe Reader can tell you). If this is the case, you have to install the type2 version of those fonts. `cm-super` (as suggested by egreg) is an easy way to do so

Comment: It is usually better to use `pdflatex` directly instead of `latex` and translating DVI to PDF.

Answer (score 4):

The cyrillic fonts you see are bitmap, so they aren't well represented in PDF viewers. Install the CM-Super font package via the MiKTeX wizard.