# Is it possible to typeset cyrillic characters as vector graphics?

Tags: languages, cyrillic

All examples [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/816/cyrillic-in-latex) seems to be vector graphics. I also have the E-book [*The LaTeX Companion, 2nd edition*](https://www.latex-project.org/help/books). The examples on pages 357/358 and 416/417 seems to be vector graphics too. With my MWE:

```
\documentclass[ngerman,russian]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\newcommand*\ngerman[1]{«\foreignlanguage{ngerman}{#1}»}

\begin{document}

  Тест. \ngerman{Test.}

\end{document}
```

I get pixelated cyrillic characters. Are there vector graphic cyrillic characters at all? If yes, what do I wrong? If not, how to explain the above examples?

**Information**: I use `TeXnicCenter`, `MiKTex`, `pdfTeX` and `Adobe Acrobat` (if this information is somehow helpful).

**Hint**: The line `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` is not needed, see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/370278/is-there-any-reason-to-use-inputenc/370280#370280).

Thank you for your help and effort in advance!

Comment: I get type1 fonts. Do you have the cm-super package installed?

Comment: No problem here with MacTeX (TeXlive) up to date: all is vectorized. Perhaps a MiKTeX issue?

Comment: Hello @Ulrike Fischer! This was the deciding hint! Thank you! An other question: Since I now using the `cm-super` package can I delete the `cm` package?

Comment: No, cm is still needed.

Comment: Probable duplicate: [Diffuse russian text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/99758).

Comment: Hello @barbara beeton! I agree. My question is a duplicate. Didn't found it earlier, shame on me.

Comment: @Su-47 -- Well, the wording of that question isn't all that obvious.  I looked in a meta question -- [Often referenced questions](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2419) -- where "likely duplicates" are listed.